# Adding a timestamp to a worksheet that already has VBA macros

Tags: excel, vba

I use a worksheet to help keep track of inventory numbers in a warehouse. I am trying to add a time stamp so I can see when I last edited a cell. I already have some VBA macros and get an ambiguous name error when I try to add the code for the time stamp.
This is the code I already have:

```
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xChangeRg As Range
Dim xDependRg As Range
Dim xDic As New Dictionary
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xDCell As Range
    Dim xHeader As String
    Dim xCommText As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    xHeader = "Previous value :"
    x = xDic.Keys
    For I = 0 To UBound(xDic.Keys)
        Set xCell = Range(xDic.Keys(I))
        Set xDCell = Cells(xCell.Row, 9)
        xDCell.Value = ""
        xDCell.Value = xDic.Items(I)
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I, J As Long
    Dim xRgArea As Range
    On Error GoTo Label1
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Set xDependRg = Target.Dependents
    If xDependRg Is Nothing Then GoTo Label1
    If Not xDependRg Is Nothing Then
        Set xDependRg = Intersect(xDependRg, Range("H:H"))
    End If
Label1:
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("G:G"))
    If (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (Not xDependRg Is Nothing) Then
        Set xChangeRg = Union(xRg, xDependRg)
    ElseIf (xRg Is Nothing) And (Not xDependRg Is Nothing) Then
        Set xChangeRg = xDependRg
    ElseIf (Not xRg Is Nothing) And (xDependRg Is Nothing) Then
        Set xChangeRg = xRg
    Else
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    xDic.RemoveAll
    For I = 1 To xChangeRg.Areas.Count
        Set xRgArea = xChangeRg.Areas(I)
        For J = 1 To xRgArea.Count
            xDic.Add xRgArea(J).Address, xRgArea(J).Value
        Next
    Next
    Set xChangeRg = Nothing
    Set xRg = Nothing
    Set xDependRg = Nothing
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This is the code I tried to add:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 20180830
Dim xCellColumn As Integer
Dim xTimeColumn As Integer
Dim xRow, xCol As Integer
Dim xDPRg, xRg As Range
xCellColumn = 10
xTimeColumn = 13
xRow = Target.Row
xCol = Target.Column
If Target.Text <> "" Then
    If xCol = xCellColumn Then
       Cells(xRow, xTimeColumn) = Now()
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set xDPRg = Target.Dependents
        For Each xRg In xDPRg
            If xRg.Column = xCellColumn Then
                Cells(xRg.Row, xTimeColumn) = Now()
            End If
        Next
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only have one `Worksheet_Change` handler in a sheet code module so you have to combine.

Comment: What would I have to change to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'first set of code
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   'second set of code
End Sub
```

which as you've found won't compile, you'd have something like

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    FirstHandler Target
    SecondHandler Target
End Sub

'next 2 subs have your original code
Private Sub FirstHandler(ByVal Target As Range)
   'first set of code
End Sub

Private Sub SecondHandler(ByVal Target As Range)
   'second set of code
End Sub
```